# How delay populates second JComboBox until first JComboBox gets selected

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have 2 JComboBox, the second gets populates from Database after an item gets selected on first JComboBox. The problem is that the second jcombobox go to populate every time I type a letter. I want to make the second jcombobox wait until the item in first jcombobox gets complete entered.

```
    private void jobCdItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                       
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED
            && jobCd.getSelectedItem() != "Select..."
            && jobCd.getSelectedItem().toString().length() > 0) {
        populatePartNoListFilter();
    }
}
```

Comment: ` The problem is that the second jcombobox go to populate every time I type a letter` in what combo do you type a letter?

Comment: populatePartNoFilter() execute every key stroke on the first combo. I want execute populatePartNoFilter() only when first combo is selected.

Answer (score 1):

A little code would help to know exactly what you are doing but my guess is that your first combo is editable and you are populating the second combo using an event listener that's being called on every key stroke.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29) using an `ActionListener` when the combo is editable should work since:

> The `ActionListener` will receive an `ActionEvent` when a selection has
>   been made. If the combo box is editable, then an ActionEvent will be
>   fired when editing has stopped.

If you are using an `ActionListener` but you still don't find the behavior fits your needs you could populate the second combo by adding a `FocusListener` on the first one and move the code that populates the second to its [`focusLost()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html#focusLost%28java.awt.event.FocusEvent%29) method.

If this option doesn't suit your needs either, I recommend reading the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) for the different available events, or give a detailed description of the behavior you are looking for so that someone might come up with a suggestion of the event handling you need to do.